# Parent value as sum of all children values within nested javascript object

Tags: javascript, recursion, lodash

I have a deeply nested javascript object with an unlimited amout of children. Every child has a value and a totalValue. The totalValue should be the sum of all the values from all its children and subchildren. How can I make this work?

At the moment I'm only able to loop the whole object using a recursive function:

```
// Recursive function
_.each(names, function(parent) { 
    if(parent.children.length > 0) { 
        recursiveFunction(parent.children);
    }
});

function recursiveFunction(children){ 
    _.each(children, function(child) { 
        if(child.children.length > 0) { 
            recursiveFunction(child.children)
        }
    });
}; 

// Deeply nested javascript object
var names = {
    name: 'name-1',
    value: 10,
    valueTotal: 0, // should be 60 (name-1.1 + name-1.2 + name-1.2.1 + name-1.2.2 + name-1.2.2.1 + name-1.2.2.2)
    children: [{
            name: 'name-1.1',
            value: 10,
            valueTotal: 0,
            children: []
        }, {
            name: 'name-1.2',
            value: 10,
            valueTotal: 0, // should be 40 (name-1.2.1 + name-1.2.2 + name-1.2.2.1 + name-1.2.2.2)
            children: [{
                name: 'name-1.2.1',
                value: 10,
                valueTotal: 0,
                children: []
            }, {
                name: 'name-1.2.2',
                value: 10,
                valueTotal: 0, // should be 20 (name-1.2.2.1 + name-1.2.2.2)
                children: [{
                    name: 'name-1.2.2.1',
                    value: 10,
                    valueTotal: 0,
                    children: []
                }, {
                    name: 'name-1.2.2.2',
                    value: 10,
                    valueTotal: 0,
                    children: []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: your sum looks wrong, name-2 is children of name-1, and should be included.

Comment: Your right! i'll change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So in fact you wanna do sth like this:
every elem asks his childs for its values, these do the same and give back their totalValues plus their own value.

```
function sumUp(object){
  object.totalValue = 0;
  for(child of object.children){
    object.totalValue += sumUp(child);
   }
   return object.totalValue + object.value;
}
```

Start like this:

```
const totalofall = sumUp(names);
console.log(names); //your expected result.
```

Working example:
http://jsbin.com/laxiveyoki/edit?console

Comment: I'm a little confused, my goal is not to get the total value of all values within the object. I'm trying to fill every totalValue of every node only with the sum  of its children/subchildren values. The result should be the same list but with all the totalValues filled in (only if that node contains children).

Comment: @Sam it does trough object.totalValue+=sumUp(children);

Comment: Have a look at the examples tree, that is logged. You will find that totalValue contains what youre searching for

Comment: I indeed looked at it totally wrong, i'll test it asap and let you know if it worked!

Comment: Please edit your response and I'll remove one downvote (my mistake, it looks like the values are actually correct)

Answer (score 2):

You could use plain Javascript with an iterative and recursive approach and some sanity checks for local totals.

```js
function calculateValues(o) {
    o.valueTotal = (o.children || []).reduce(function (r, a) {
        calculateValues(a);    
        return r + (a.value || 0) + (a.valueTotal || 0);
    }, 0);
}

var names = { name: 'name-1', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [{ name: 'name-1.1', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [] }, { name: 'name-1.2', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [{ name: 'name-1.2.1', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [] }, { name: 'name-1.2.2', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [{ name: 'name-1.2.2.1', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [] }, { name: 'name-1.2.2.2', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [] }] }] }] };

calculateValues(names);
console.log(names);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a big fan of reinventing the wheel and would suggest to use a library for readability and maintainability. We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) now for most of our data processing. It is quite versatile once you wrap your head around how to use it. Anyways, here is a possible solution for your question

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const injectSums = (data) => {
  objectScan(['**.children'], {
    filterFn: ({ parent, value: children }) => {
      parent.valueTotal = children
        .map(({ valueTotal, value }) => valueTotal + value)
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    }
  })(data);
};

const names = { name: 'name-1', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [ { name: 'name-1.1', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [] }, { name: 'name-1.2', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [ { name: 'name-1.2.1', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [] }, { name: 'name-1.2.2', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [ { name: 'name-1.2.2.1', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [] }, { name: 'name-1.2.2.2', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [] } ] } ] }] };

injectSums(names);

console.log(names);
// => { name: 'name-1', value: 10, valueTotal: 60, children: [ { name: 'name-1.1', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [] }, { name: 'name-1.2', value: 10, valueTotal: 40, children: [ { name: 'name-1.2.1', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [] }, { name: 'name-1.2.2', value: 10, valueTotal: 20, children: [ { name: 'name-1.2.2.1', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [] }, { name: 'name-1.2.2.2', value: 10, valueTotal: 0, children: [] } ] } ] } ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Comment: If you want to go through old questions and show how `object-scan` might help answer them, feel free, and if this is just your new hammer and hence everything looks like a nail, that's fine too.  But if you have a significant connection to `object-scan` please include a disclaimer.  (For instance, when discussing Ramda, I add something like "(disclaimer: I'm one of Ramda's principal authors)".)  Because it feels as though you're trying to sell something here.

Comment: Please try to write a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992) for JS answers.  You can use something like `<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.6.6"></script>` instead of your `import` statement.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thank you for the feedback. My intention was obviously not to sell anything, but rather use these old questions as a learning exercise for myself. But you are absolute right and I'll go through my answers and update them later with a disclaimer.

Comment: A disclaimer is important if you're connected to the library (as perhaps a major contributor or funder.)  Otherwise, it's not necessary.  I'm just seeing your same intro over a number of recent answers to old questions, and I wondered about it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. It adds previous count value in object to total count. This can be subtracted later

```
function sumUpTree(obj, key, totalKey, childrenKey) {
  
  let sumUpTreeInner = (obj) => {
    obj[totalKey] =
      obj[key] +
      (obj[childrenKey] || []).reduce(function (r, child) {
        sumUpTreeInner(child);
        return r + (child[totalKey] || 0);
      }, 0);
  };
  sumUpTreeInner(obj);
}
```

This is inspired from above answers of [Jonas Wilms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41746086/10824740) and [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41746373/10824740)